# Continuity proving of function with delta-epsilon

Tags: proof-verification, continuity

Prove continuity of function with the delta-epsilon definition in point $x_o=0$
$$f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$
$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x^2+1,  & x \in  \mathbb{Q} \\[2ex]
2^x, & x \in \mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}
\end{cases} $$

What I've done: 
I know that I know that in order to do so I must find that for any $\epsilon >0$, there exists a $\delta >0$ so that for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$ with $\left|x-x_o\right|<\delta $ we have $\left|f\left(x\right)-f\left(x_o\right)\right|<\epsilon \:$

We can see right off the bat that $f(x_o)=1$
So I must prove that $\left|x\right|<\delta $ implies $\left|f\left(x\right)-1\right|<\epsilon $

For when $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ I must prove that $\left|x\right|<\delta $ implies $\:\left|x^2\right|<\epsilon $, so I can just choose $\delta =\:\sqrt{\epsilon }$.

For the other case when $x \in \mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$ I must prove that $\left|x\right|<\delta $ implies $\left|2^x-1\right|<\epsilon $
I know that $\left|2^x-1\right|\le \left|2^x\right|+1\le 2^{\left|x\right|}+1<2^{\delta }+1$ which would imply that $\delta =\:\frac{ln\left(\epsilon -1\right)}{ln\:2}$

So in the end I can just choose $\delta =\:min\left\{\frac{ln\left(\epsilon -1\right)}{ln\:2},\sqrt{\epsilon }\right\}$ and be done with it?

I'm a little bit unsure of these exercises, since I don't really have many examples to go by. Did I get something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly right!
Congratulations!

Comment: What if I had $f\left(x\right)=ln\left(x+1\right)$ for one of the cases? How could I write that in relation to my $\delta$ or $\epsilon$ ?

Comment: But 
$ ln(0+1)=0 $ so $f$ would not be continuous for sure...